# Peer Not Authenticated Error when Using Sonar for Bamboo

Tags: ssl, https, sonarqube, bamboo, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to connect to a server with a https url, but when I enter the information into Bamboo I get
"An error occurred while connecting the given SonarQube server: peer not authenticated".
I added the server's certificate to cacert and /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt but still have the same issue. Has anyone else faced this issue/have suggestions of how to resolve the problem? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To help you we need many information: SQ server version, Scanner type (CLI, Maven, Gradle, MSBuild ...) and version. Also you should try to enable debug logs for SSL by adding JVM argument -Djavax.net.debug=all. Please provide stacktrace of the error + SSL logs.

Comment: SonarQube server version 5.6.1. Sonar Maven 3 scanner type. I cannot enable debugging as the error shows up when I am entering the server's configuration details for the add on and will not let me proceed until that error is resolved.

Comment: From what you say there seems to be some connection made by the Bamboo plugin itself. Since we are not maintaining it, I'm sorry I can't help.